# In CKEDITOR.revision == ( '%RE' + 'V%' ) What Javascript technique is used?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor4.x

```
function isWysiwygareaAvailable() {
        // If in development mode, then the wysiwygarea must be available.
        // Split REV into two strings so builder does not replace it :D.
        if ( CKEDITOR.revision == ( '%RE' + 'V%' ) ) {
            return true;
        }

        return !!CKEDITOR.plugins.get( 'wysiwygarea' );
    }
```

I found this code in CKeditor 4.9.0 custom build. Why REV is split into two strings? What javascript technique is used?

Comment: It is explained in the comment above the statement. And it is not related to JavaScript. The builder mentioned in the comment is probably a tool that combines the myriad of small files that contain the code of the editor into a single big file that is published.

Comment: They probably have a configuration in the build server to replace all instances of word `%REV%` with the actual version ID. So on developer machines the version would be `%REV%`, whereas on the built library it would be actual version number such as `4.9.0`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as Primarily opinion based because the answer would require some speculation as to what build process they are using, unless someone from the *inside* decides to explain stuff.

Answer (score 1):

CKEditor is built using [build.sh](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/major/dev/builder/build.sh), which in turn calls

```
java -jar ckbuilder/$CKBUILDER_VERSION/ckbuilder.jar
```

the source of which is also on [GitHub](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckbuilder).

There, the function `processDirectives()` in file [tools.js](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckbuilder/blob/85f532623210ceba631d9c79e56f5554758076eb/src/lib/tools.js) replaces occurrences of `%Version%` and `%Revision%` with the command-line parameters passed to ckbuilder.

Since this replacement takes only place for a distribution build, the development source code still contains the unprocessed `%REV%`. This fact is used to distinguish between dev and prod source.

Splitting the string `%REV%` simply avoids its replacement, as it is used as a reference value here.